# How to set different animation.duration times for point 1 to 2 and point 2 to 3 of an imageView following a BezierPath in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, caanimation

I have a UIView subview with a BezierPath and an ImageView that follows the path from a to b. The path has 8 points and I need point 1 to point 2 to have a different duration that point 2 to point 3 etc

I've been able to set up the view and path and animate the image along the path but with the same duration time for the full animation. Here is my code for the animation, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
let pathToFollow = path
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.position))
    animation.path = pathToFollow?.cgPath
    animation.duration = 10.0
    animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced
    animation.delegate = self
    self.icons[Icon].layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a keyframe animation, which is a good start. But you forgot to add some actual frames! To do so, supply some `keyTimes`. (And remove the `kCAAnimationPaced`; it means that the whole animation has a single speed, which is the opposite of what you said you wanted.)

Note that with a path animation of this sort, the frame division points are the bezier points used to define the path, so everything will depend on how the path was constructed in the first place.

Here's an actual example:

[image]

Observe how we speed up at each corner as we proceed round the square. The corners are where the control points are. Here's the code I used:

```
    let path = CGPath(rect: CGRect(x: 120, y: 120, width: 100, height: 100), 
        transform: nil)
    let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.position))
    anim.duration = 10
    anim.path = path
    anim.calculationMode = .linear
    anim.keyTimes = [0.0, 0.7, 0.9, 0.98, 1.0]
    self.v.layer.add(anim, forKey: nil)
```